# is it possible to set label value from related model in datacolumn in gridview in yii2

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

Related to my question I have searched alot on internet but didnot find answer to my question.

I am try to accomplish a simple task in gridview in yii2, details are as follow.

```
<?=
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'id',
        'Name',
        'Email:email',
        'Phone',
        'Age',
        [
            'class' => yii\grid\DataColumn::className(),
            'label' =>'Custom',
            'attribute' => 'cusId',
            'format'=>'html',
            'value' => function ($model) {
                return Html::a($model->cus->Key, ['customobj/view', 'id' => $model->cusId],['class' => 'btn btn-success']);
            },
            'filter' => yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(app\models\Customobj::find()->all(), 'Id', 'Key')
        ],
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]);
?>
```

The above code working fine. Now I want to make the lable dynamic from related model in following.

```
[
        'class' => yii\grid\DataColumn::className(),
        'label' =>'Custom',
        'attribute' => 'cusId',
        'format'=>'html',
        'value' => function ($model) {
            return Html::a($model->cus->Key, ['customobj/view', 'id' => $model->cusId],['class' => 'btn btn-success']);
        },
        'filter' => yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(app\models\Customobj::find()->all(), 'Id', 'Key')
    ],
```

I have tried below code but it gives

> Blockquote
>   htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
>   Blockquote

```
[
            'class' => yii\grid\DataColumn::className(),
            'label' => function ($model) {
                return $model->cus->Key;
            },
            'attribute' => 'cusId',
            'format'=>'html',
            'value' => function ($model) {
                return Html::a($model->cus->Key, ['customobj/view', 'id' => $model->cusId],['class' => 'btn btn-success']);
            },
            'filter' => yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(app\models\Customobj::find()->all(), 'Id', 'Key')
        ],
```

I am using yii2 version.
any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using header

```
$varHeader = yourFuntion();

[
        'class' => yii\grid\DataColumn::className(),
        'header' =>  $varHeader ,
        'attribute' => 'cusId',
        'format'=>'html',
        'value' => function ($model) {
            return Html::a($model->cus->Key, ['customobj/view', 'id' => $model->cusId],['class' => 'btn btn-success']);
        },
        'filter' => yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(app\models\Customobj::find()->all(), 'Id', 'Key')
    ],
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @scaisEdge.
I will check and update here

Comment: got below error:
trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Comment: Just a curiosity ... you need change the header row by row or the row header is fixed for every rows and change only when you cange the page or the models collections?

Comment: Actually I am grouping all the records that will have one common column in data base say KEY, but obviously it will changed to another column as key is user as value for this field.

Comment: The header and the label only accept string and not function .. then you can obtain what you need calculating the value and assign in to a string var outside the gridview and in  gridview assign the value  at this var.. i have update the answer  this way

Comment: I like this approach,
finally I will use this if didnot find anyother :)

Comment: Instead of "header", "label" is good, as label make it sort able :)

Comment: OK label also is good and like you say is sortable.. well i hope this is useful for you..